# Internal Network not getting IP when connecting raspberry PI and windows via cabel

Tags: windows, dhcp, raspberry-pi

Setup:

Raspberry PI with raspbian os installed connected via Ethernet cable to my PC (windows 10)

Ethernet connection that are created got ip range `169. ...` meaning cannot get DHCP server.

In my network configuration under IPv4 i got  Obtain IP address automatically and Obtain DNS server automatically.

I can see green lights under Ethernet cable on both raspberry pi and PC.

What i am doing wrong? Why my windows cannot obtain an IP automatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting `link-local` address assignment on the Raspberry Pi because your Windows network connection is not *shared.*

In general this is called a **network bridge.** On Windows, a network bridge is created when the user selects "Allow Other Network Users to Connect through This Computer’s Internet Connection"

See this question [Share Windows computer internet connection with Raspberry Pi](https://superuser.com/questions/759822/share-windows-computer-internet-connection-with-raspberry-pi)

**On Automatic IP address assignment**

*DHCP*

The usual method of *automatically* assigning IP addresses is through the use of a network DHCP server.  In many home networks, the DHCP server is included on the router... which is usually, but doesn't need to be, also a WiFi Router.

So, if your question is:

**How do I get my Raspberry Pi to have an automatically assigned address on my LAN while it is connected via an Ethernet cable to my Windows PC?**

the answer is:

**Create a network bridge between your LAN connected network interface on your Windows PC and your Ethernet connected Raspberry Pi.**

If you do not want your Raspberry Pi to have Internet access, you can configure a static lease on your router for the Pi and configure your router's firewall rules to disable `FORWARDING` for statically assigned lease address.

Of course, methods for setting up a static address and configuring the firewall will depend on your individual router.

Comment: I am not sure i understand. I don't want raspberry to be able to connect to internet. I want to connect to raspberry in my internal network.

Comment: After you added details i understood everything. All working now. My assumption that windows will by default will forward DHCP request to router was wrong. Thanks.